Android studio Gradle build error: Could not find com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0
I'm new to Android development. I get this error from both Android Studio and ns build android:
Build file 'C:\Progetti\APP\src\app-mobile\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 577
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not find com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app

I updated my build.gradle file with the suggested config from https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter
repositories {
    // used for local *.AAR files
    pluginDependencies = nativescriptDependencies.collect {
        "$rootDir/${it.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID"
    }

    // some plugins may have their android dependencies in a /libs subdirectory
    pluginDependencies.addAll(nativescriptDependencies.collect {
        "$rootDir/${it.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID/libs"
    })

    if (!externalRuntimeExists) {
        pluginDependencies.add("libs/runtime-libs")
    }

    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def localAppResourcesLibraries = "$appResourcesPath/Android/libs"

    pluginDependencies.add(localAppResourcesLibraries)

    if (pluginDependencies.size() > 0) {
        flatDir {
            dirs pluginDependencies
        }
    }

    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}


dependencies {
    .
    .
    .

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$androidXMultidexVersion"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidXAppCompatVersion"
    debugImplementation "com.google.android.material:material:$androidXMaterialVersion"
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:$androidXExifInterfaceVersion"
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:$androidXViewPagerVersion"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$androidXFragmentVersion"
    implementation "androidx.transition:transition:$androidXTransitionVersion"
    implementation "com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0"

    def useV8Symbols = false

    def appPackageJsonFile = file("${getAppPath()}/$PACKAGE_JSON")
    if (appPackageJsonFile.exists()) {
        def appPackageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(appPackageJsonFile.text)
        useV8Symbols = appPackageJson.android && appPackageJson.android.useV8Symbols
    }

    if (!useV8Symbols) {
        // check whether any of the dependencies require v8 symbols
        useV8Symbols = nativescriptDependencies.any {
            def packageJsonFile = file("$rootDir/${it.directory}/$PACKAGE_JSON")
            def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(packageJsonFile.text)
            return packageJson.nativescript && packageJson.nativescript.useV8Symbols
        }
    }

All this config has been initially generated by ns build android and I get the same error when I run such command.
What am I missing? Thanks in advance, any help is really appreciated.

This is happening due to nativescript-feedback plugin
There is a solution but this is not a permanent solution.

Solution
1.  Find the file "include.gradle" in following location
..\<project_folder>\node_modules\nativescript-feedback\platforms\android

2. Add following changes to the file "include.gradle"
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.Tapadoo:Alerter:7.1.0'
}

*** Before changing the file
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def supportVer = "27.0.1"
    if (project.hasProperty("supportVersion")) {
        supportVer = supportVersion
    }
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVer"
    implementation "com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
}

*** After adding changes to the file
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } <<<===== NEW ADDING
}

dependencies {
    def supportVer = "27.0.1"
    if (project.hasProperty("supportVersion")) {
        supportVer = supportVersion
    }
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVer"
    implementation 'com.github.Tapadoo:Alerter:7.1.0' <<<===== NEW ADDING
    // implementation "com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0" <<<===== EXSISTING ONE COMMENTED
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
}



This worked for me.


I updated my build.gradle file with the suggested config from https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter

You have:
implementation "com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0"

They have:
implementation 'com.github.tapadoo:alerter:$current-version'

You have com.tapadoo.android as the artifact group. This library used to use that, years ago. Their current instructions have com.github.tapadoo as the artifact group, which is not what you have. And, for com.github.tapadoo, $current-version is 7.2.4, as of today.
So, you should use:
implementation "com.github.tapadoo:alerter:7.2.4"


Unfortunately it did not work, I still get the same error.

@LNyarla: Since the error specifically refers to 6.1.0 (Could not find com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0), are you sure that you get the same error? If you did, then whatever change you made did not take effect.

Restarted my pc and Android studio, now I get "Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/tapadoo/android/alerter/6.1.0/alerter-6.1.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized"

@LNyarla: You did not make the change outlined in my answer, or there is something else in your project that is still trying to retrieve the wrong artifact.

Solved this way, in build.gradle:
allprojects {
    configurations {
        all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                dependencySubstitution {
                    substitute(module("com.tapadoo.android:alerter:6.1.0"))
                            .using(module("com.github.tapadoo:alerter:7.2.4"))
                            .because("401 error in main repo")
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

In dependencies section
dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.tapadoo:alerter:7.2.4"
}


I guess your are talking about the file platforms/android/build.gradle. Command 'ns clean' will delete this file. You can move your change to App_Resources/Android/app.gradle or something equivalent => See https://old.docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/gradle-hooks

This is happening with nativescript-feedback plugin in my codebase.
The above library is one of those jitpack issues of old, you can just switch your project to use this one:
https://github.com/valor-software/nativescript-plugins/tree/master/packages/nativescript-feedback

After the removal of nativescript-feedback and adding https://github.com/valor-software/nativescript-plugins/tree/master/packages/nativescript-feedback resolved the gradle build issue.
